# Requestmethod POST not supported || Spring login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I got an error, when trying to login on my page when starting maven tomcat on eclipse.

"There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported"

I aleady included csrf token in the form.
Maybe you can help e solving this.

WebSecurity:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
// Authentication : User --> Roles
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.
            inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("1234")
            .roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("5678")
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}

// Authorization : Role -> Access
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/cont/**").access("hasRole('USER') or 
hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")

            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/loginForm.html")                                  
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/login-success", true)                   
                .loginProcessingUrl("/performLogin")
                .failureUrl("/failLogin.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll().logoutUrl("/logout")

            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable();
}

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return super.userDetailsService();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
Exception {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder pe = new  BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(pe);
}

}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/performLogin", method= {RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView loginForm() {
    return new ModelAndView("loginForm.html");
}

//Login Success    
@RequestMapping(value = "/login-success", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginSuccess() {
    return new ModelAndView("/cont/home.html");
}
}
```

HTML

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:include="layout :: head(title=~{::title},links=~{})">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Please Login</title>
<link href="styles/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body th:include="layout :: body" th:with="content=~{::content}">
<div th:fragment="content" id="formLogin">
    <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

            <div id="sign">A</div>

            <article id="formContent">
                <div class="inpt">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" 
placeholder="Username"/>
                </div>

                <div class="inpt">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" 
placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" 
value="${_csrf.token}"/>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
            </article>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Stacktrace:

```
    2018-10-10 14:03:13.642  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] model.MainApplicationClass               : Starting MainApplicationClass on PGES0074 with PID 3448 (C:\Users\KroemerT\eclipse-workspace\TestOne\target\classes started by kroemert in C:\Users\KroemerT\eclipse-workspace\TestOne)
    2018-10-10 14:03:13.646  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] model.MainApplicationClass               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2018-10-10 14:03:13.760  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@674dbea2: startup date [Wed Oct 10 14:03:13 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    2018-10-10 14:03:15.213  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils      : Failed to introspect annotations on [class org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration]: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    2018-10-10 14:03:15.214  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils      : Failed to introspect annotations on [class org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration]: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    2018-10-10 14:03:17.071  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2018-10-10 14:03:17.089  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
    2018-10-10 14:03:17.091  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
    2018-10-10 14:03:17.442  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    2018-10-10 14:03:17.447  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2018-10-10 14:03:17.447  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3692 ms
    2018-10-10 14:03:18.101  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-10-10 14:03:18.102  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-10-10 14:03:18.102  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-10-10 14:03:18.102  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-10-10 14:03:18.102  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-10-10 14:03:18.104  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
    2018-10-10 14:03:18.104  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-10-10 14:03:18.105  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-10-10 14:03:18.105  INFO 3448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
    2018-10-10 14:03:18.965  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant [pattern='/webjars/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant [pattern='/error']]], []
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.075  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3b1fae40, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@14d2b09e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@67aff8eb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@26763c4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@38a45f15, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6f2af3e3, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4aab9820, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@68d7b4ed, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@62ffcb8e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@39fa5fc8, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@7e08d83]
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.094  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration$LazyEndpointPathRequestMatcher@38184e5f, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1eb61155, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@9eabf8a, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2a54667a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@276a4420, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2bc67089, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@112a0e5a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@18c4ddb3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6ec6832, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@f55a142, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5ad85015, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@564e18d9]
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.203  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@674dbea2: startup date [Wed Oct 10 14:03:13 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.301  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/document/all],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<model.Document> model.DocumentController.getAll()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.303  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/document/new],methods=[POST]}" onto public void model.DocumentController.addDocument(model.Document)
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.303  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/document/remove],methods=[GET]}" onto public void model.DocumentController.removeUser()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.303  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/performLogin],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView model.DocumentController.loginForm()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.303  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login-success],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView model.DocumentController.loginSuccess()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.304  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/logout],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView model.DocumentController.logoutPage(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.304  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/loggeduser],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String model.DocumentController.printUsername(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,java.security.Principal)
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.304  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/document/date],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String model.DocumentController.gDate()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.308  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.309  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.336  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.336  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/people] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.336  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/home] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.356  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.356  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.429  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.920  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.920  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.922  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.923  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.925  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.925  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.927  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.928  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.929  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.934  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.935  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.936  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2018-10-10 14:03:19.937  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2018-10-10 14:03:20.079  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
    2018-10-10 14:03:20.187  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
    2018-10-10 14:03:20.211  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
    2018-10-10 14:03:20.417  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
    2018-10-10 14:03:20.424  INFO 3448 --- [  restartedMain] model.MainApplicationClass               : Started MainApplicationClass in 7.348 seconds (JVM running for 7.937)
    2018-10-10 14:06:20.381  INFO 3448 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    2018-10-10 14:06:20.382  INFO 3448 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
    2018-10-10 14:06:20.401  INFO 3448 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 19 ms
    2018-10-10 14:06:20.469  WARN 3448 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
    2018-10-10 14:06:20.470  WARN 3448 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
    2018-10-10 14:06:34.683  WARN 3448 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
    2018-10-10 14:06:34.684  WARN 3448 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

I read through many similar question asked here but couldnt find a solution.

Comment: `login` where is the mapping.? In your controller it is `/user-login"`. In your configuration it is `performLogin`. So where the login request goes?

Comment: So i should set everyhing to the same path?
The loginProcessingUrl, JSP and the mapping?

Comment: of course......

Comment: Well, I did but still the same problem.

And sorry, I'm pretty new to spring.

Comment: Clean and Build the project. Please try to include stacktrace in question.

Comment: I read the following:

"The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured."

maybe it could be cause i included my project from IntelliJ to Eclipse?

Comment: Ya. You should stop all tomcat running instances.

Comment: @ SadmirD Well, I hope I don't. 

So, what do you need for insight?
Shall I post my whole stacktrace?

Comment: If it is programming related post stacktrace else it is environment related no need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is issue in this line in both method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login-success", method = {RequestMethod.POST, 
RequestMethod.GET})
```

You have configured both GET and POST for a rest call

Try this

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login-success", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Can you add "/login" method. As in your JSP page you are doing POST call with url "/login"

Comment: What shall this /login method do?

Comment: You are asking me?  This url is responsible for getting username and password and validate. I do see you have added "loginProcessingUrl"  may be you need to replace "login"  with "performLogin" in JSP

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people brainstorm over "the same code that works there but not here" all day long, only to figure out that they did't allow/set up their desired method in **CORS** settings. That'd be my best guess.

The biggest lesson for you is not to make wild guesses, though, but to utilize tools such as **advanced REST client, postman, your browser's dev tools**. I.e. you can easily confirm whether CORS filter is an issue if you check the response headers in your browser.
To open dev tools in google chrome, press CTRL + SHIFT + J. Your main preoccupation would be the network tab for this particular case, in order to check out whether you have the required headers. POST method requires CORS filters being set up properly by default.

Comment: And how do i check if these filters are set up?

Comment: Check out for CorsFilter or some other class that you defined, the one that implements your Filter. If you didn't create it, then you'll need to do it yourself. In fact, this can be done on multiple ways, including xml configuration, so I am not sure about what's convenient for your specifc case and what your spring framework version supports. This link would be much more helpful in order to get a start, pay attention it's spring 4.x: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-rest-cors-integration-using-crossorigin-annotation-xml-filter-example

Answer (score -1):

Actually you don't need a post method for login because spring security is managing that. You only need a GET login method. Try to delete your POST login.

Comment: I changed it to that:

.loginPage("/loginForm.html")           
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/login-success", true)                   
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/performLogin")
                    .failureUrl("/failLogin.html")

and:

@RequestMapping(value="/performLogin", method= {RequestMethod.GET})
@RequestMapping(value = "/login-success", method=RequestMethod.GET)

But still get POST Error

Comment: .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().loginPage("login").permitAll().loginProcessingUrl("login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password") .defaultSuccessUrl("/").failureUrl("/error").userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
.and()  .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();

Comment: that's my login my GET                                         @GetMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(required = false, name = "error") String error, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");

        if(error != null) modelAndView.addObject("error", error);

        return modelAndView;
    }

Comment: [Actually you don't need a post method for login because spring security is managing that. You only need a GET login method]


And expose your user name and password in the URL address bar?